# Initial Value Problem: $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=3-e^{2t};\;y(1)=-1;\;y'(1)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=3-e^{2t};\;y(1)=-1;\;y'(1)=0$$

I have never done initial value problems before, and this is very similar to one problem that is on my homework, I am trying to solve this to get a more clear picture on how to solve the one on my homework.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: The problem is an initial value problem.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific. What does "∫ dy/(√(169+y^2))" have to do with the question?

Comment: We are given $y''(t)=3-e^{2t}$. Integrate. We get $y'(t)=3t-\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}+C$. Use $y'(1)$ to evaluate $C$. Now use a similar procedure to get $y(t)$.

Comment: oh man I'm dumb sorry I accidentally ctrl+v that there... thank you for letting me know

Comment: so c= 1/2 e^2-3?

Comment: So you're saying i need to integrate y'(t) to get y(t) which will be my answer right?

Comment: Good, indeed you got $C$ right. Now integrate again, and use $y(1)$ to identify the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=3-e^{2t};\;y(1)=-1;\;y'(1)=0$$
This is actually simpler than you think. You're given the second derivative. How do you get the first derivative? Just integrate:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\int \left(3-e^{2t}\right)dt=3t-\frac12e^{2t}+C$$

You're given that $y'(1)=\frac{dy}{dt}\Big|_{t=1}=0$, allowing you to find this $C$:

$$0=3(1)-\frac12e^{2(1)}+C \\C=\frac12e^2-3$$

So we are left with:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3t-\frac12e^{2t}+\frac12e^2-3$$

Now to find $y$? Easy, integrate again:

$$y=\int \left(3t-\frac12e^{2t}+\frac12e^2-3\right) dt=\frac32t^2-\frac14e^{2t}+\frac12e^2t-3t+C$$

Finding $C$ is very simple again, since you're given $y(1)=-1$...
$$-1=\frac32(1)^2-\frac14e^{2(1)}+\frac12e^2(1)-3(1)+C=\frac32-\frac14e^2+\frac12e^2-3+C \\ C=-1-\frac32+3+\frac14e^2-\frac12e^2=\frac12-\frac14e^2$$

Giving us a final equation of:

$$y=\frac32t^2-\frac14e^{2t}+\frac12e^2t-3t + \frac12-\frac14e^2$$

Comment: Thank you for actually working it out, I will compare this to my problem!

Comment: @Jason Okay but just remember that I may have made mistakes. Make sure you double check my work ^_^.

Comment: @Jason: I can see that you really did make up this problem. Usually when one makes up such problems for a test, one makes sure there are fewer terms at the end!

Comment: haha yeah thanks for noticing, and thanks for all of the help both of you!